# onDismiss function in snackbar doesn't work in react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I'm building mobile application with `react-native` and `react-native-paper`.
And I'm using `SnackBar` component in `react-native-paper`, and if I use `SnackBar` component directly, `onDismiss` function in `SnackBar` component works well. (It means the snackbar will disappear correctly)

But if I use my original component(like `SnackBarComponent` component) which uses `SnackBar` component provided `react-native-paper`, somehow, the snackbar will not disappear correctly.

This is my custom SnackBar Component and the code which calls my original SnackBar Component.

- My original SnackBar Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Provider, Snackbar } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class SnackBarComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      snackbarVisible: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Provider>
        <Snackbar
          visible={this.props.snackbarVisible}
          onDismiss={() => this.setState({ snackbarVisible: false })}
        >
          <Text>{this.props.snackbarText}</Text>
        </Snackbar>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

- The code which calls SnackBarComponent(This is not whole code)

```
import SnackBarComponent from './components/SnackBarComponent';

:

handleShowSnackbar() {
  this.setState({
    snackbarVisible: true,
    snackbarText: 'show snackbar'
  })
}

:

<SnackBarComponent snackbarVisible={this.state.snackbarVisible} snackbarText={this.state.snackbarText}/>

:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a state containing `snackbarVisible` which is local to `SnackBarComponent` and it is initially `false`.

Then you have `snackbarVisible` in the parent component state where it's local to the parent component. It is not the same as `snackbarVisible` in `SnackBarComponent`.

In case you did not specifically defined a state in parent component containing `snackbarVisible`, please note that when you run `setState` method it will create `snackbarVisible` in the `state` if not found one.

When you are updating `snackbarVisible`(dismiss in this case) you have to update the one you defined here `visible={this.props.snackbarVisible}` which is containing the `snackbarVisible` in the parent component through the props. Which means you have to update the parent component's `snackbarVisible`. For that you can pass a callback to the `SnackBarComponent` and update the right value in the parent component. Here's an example:

```
    //parent component
    import SnackBarComponent from './components/SnackBarComponent';

    :

    handleShowSnackbar() {
      this.setState({
        snackbarVisible: true,
        snackbarText: 'show snackbar'
      })
    }

//add a function to update the parents state
    handleDismissSnackbar = () => {
      this.setState({
        snackbarVisible: false,
      })
    }

    :

    <SnackBarComponent snackbarVisible={this.state.snackbarVisible}
                       snackbarText={this.state.snackbarText}
                       dismissSnack={this.handleDismissSnackbar}/>   //add here
```

Then the children component `SnackBarComponent` in this case as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Provider, Snackbar } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class SnackBarComponent extends Component {
//you dont need to maintain this local state anymore for this purpose  
/*constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      snackbarVisible: false
    }
  }*/

  render() {
    return(
      <Provider>
        <Snackbar
          visible={this.props.snackbarVisible}
          onDismiss={() => this.props.dismissSnack()}   //use that function here
        >
          <Text>{this.props.snackbarText}</Text>
        </Snackbar>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Now when you press dismiss, it will call the `handleDismissSnackbar` in parent component by `dismissSnack` passed through the props.

this is controlling from parent. Example of controlled components. You can find about it more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components